# Зеркальное копирование с помощью rsync

Tags: linux, nginx, резервное-копирование, rsync, certbot

Есть следующая система:

Около 20 хостов, с которых копируются 3 директории сертбота - renewal, live, archives. Все копируется на один резервный хост, на который переключается проект, в случае падения основного сервера. Если со старыми сертами доменов сертботу живется хорошо, то вот от конфигов в renewal ему рвет крышу, и тест вебсервера(nginx) фейлится. Бекапится все с помощью скрипта с rsync-ом. Есть ли возможность сделать зеркальное копирование директории renewal? Т.е. если я удалю домен test.com, должен удалиться домен на основном хосте, а при попытке сделать бекап, rsync чекает, что такого файла нет и тоже его удаляет на резервном хосте.

Comment: `$ rsync --delete ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rsync чекает, что такого файла нет и тоже его удаляет на резервном хосте

для этого служит опция `--delete` программы *rsync*:

```
$ rsync --delete прочие-опции-и-параметры
```

при её наличии, если на стороне-получателе присутствует файл/каталог, а на стороне-источнике такового нет, то файл/каталог будет удалён на стороне-получателе.

согласно man-странице программы *rsync*, момент удаления при наличии такой опции не определён. это можно изменить, употребив вместо (или вместе) одну из уточняющих опций:

- `--delete-before` — удалять до начала передачи содержимого файлов
- `--delete-during` — удалять во время передачи
- `--delete-after` — удалять после завершения передачи
- `--delete-delay` — практически то же, что и `--delete-after`, за исключением использования более нового не-инкрементального алгоритма составления списка файлов на удаление.

при использовании перечисленных опций настоятельно рекомендуется сначала добавить опцию `--dry-run` (`-n`), чтобы увидеть, какие действия будут произведены программой.

---

доп. чтение: `$ man rsync`

Comment: Лично я юзаю `--delete --delete-after --delete-excluded`. Точно вычищает всё на том хосте **на который** бэкапится. Ещё можно посмотреть в сторону `lsyncd`.

Comment: @donRumata, 1. опции `--delete-*` **уже** подразумевают (implied) опцию `--delete`. 2. опция `--delete-excluded` имеет смысл только при наличии опции `--exclude=...`

Comment: По поводу `только при наличии опции --exclude` не совсем согласен. Хз почему, но без неё у меня не всегда удаляются "мусорные" файлы. Надо конечно по-подробнее покопать, но в своё время времени убил порядочно.

Comment: К сожалению, это не подходит. Такой метод удаляет все остальные сертификаты.

Comment: Хотя, подходит. Если все копировать в отдельные директории, после этого сливать актуальные серты в один каталог и синхронизировать его с помощью --delete до актуальных версий. Спасибо!